# remove line of words from a response data - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my response data from an angularjs json response data I have the following words when consoled as shown

```
$rootScope.myData = res.data;
//the above contains
1. Titles of Variations
2. In Sports
3. Going to Gym
4. My Car Runs Faster
6. Account Setup
```

From the json response assigned to myData scope, I want to remove line 1 and 4 so that myData contains only line 2,3and 6. Kindly assist

Comment: `res.data[1].name` is it a plain string?

Comment: it was typo. is an array

Comment: Then you could simply use filter to exclude things that you don't want, something like `data.filter((item, index) => { return index !== 0 && index !== 3 })`. I considered 1 as 0 and 4 as 3 because index start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object with line numbers as a key and then use filter to exclude 1 and 4

```js
const str = `Titles of Variations
In Sports
Going to Gym
My Car Runs Faster
Account Setup`;

console.log(str); 

const line = ['1', '4'];

const obj = str.split("\n").reduce((accu,curr, i) => {
  accu[i+1] =  curr;
  return accu;
}, {});

const output = Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, _]) => !line.includes(key)).map((arr) => arr[1]).join("\n");

console.log(output);
```

Comment: const obj = res.data.split( is not function

Comment: Then `res.data` is not a string object, since `split` is part of string object